# Clicking on a SVG icon to mark a checbox - Protractor - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, protractor

I wonder if someone can help me on this one :)
I'm struggling to select one icon on my e2e test with protractor (using TypeScript).
So Heres some of my code, and also the path.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const animalsInterest = element(By.css(''));
var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(animalsInterest); 

return  browser.wait(isClickable, 5000),
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", animalsInterest.getWebElement());
```

This is my actual code (i wasn't able to find the correct selector, so I've maintained by.css).

The icon that I want to grab is below;

```
<fa-icon _ngcontent-c16="" class="check-box-font unchecked ng-fa-icon ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-icon-prop="[object Object]"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm16 400c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V80c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h352c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v352z"></path></svg></fa-icon>
```

Is there a way for me to use getOuterHTml or something like that?
Thanks for the help! Good coding for you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try by xpath:
by.xpath(.//fa-icon[contains(@class,'check-box-font')])

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use;

```
element(By.xpath('//fa-icon[contains(@class,'check-box-font')])
```

but it's telling that something is wrong

',' expected.ts(1005)
Cannot find name 'check'.ts(2304)
Expected 1 argument, but got 3.ts(2554)